# How to get tree node selected in a TreeNode structure in ZK?

Tags: java, zk, treenode, jooq

I have created a tree depending upon the number of parent nodes and children nodes of a selectedData but after rendering the tree I don't know the node of the selecteddata which I have to make selected byDefault. So how could I search the required node and make it selected?

```
<tree model="@load(vm.peopleTreeModel)"
        selectedItem="@load(vm.selectedPeopleTreeNode)"
        sizedByContent="true" droppable="true" width="100%" vflex="1"
        hflex="1" visible="@load(vm.relatedView)">
        <template name="model" var="node">
            <treeitem open="@bind(node.open)">
                <treerow>
                    <treecell
                        label="@bind(node.data.name)" sclass="field-label"
                        onClick="@command('showPeopleDetailFromTree' , peopleRSN=node.data.description)"
                        onDoubleClick="@command('showPeopleDetailOnDoubleClickFromTree' , peopleRSN=node.data.description)" />
                    </treerow>
                </treeitem>
            </template>
        </tree>
```

and our view model

```
public void createPeopleTreeModel(int argpeopleID) {
        parentNodeChildList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        treeNodeMap = new HashMap<Integer, DemoTreeNode>();
        Integer peopleID;
        List<Integer> peopleIDList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (Integer peopleId : childrenList) {
            peopleIDList.add(peopleId);
            String peopleName = Services.peopleService().getPeopleNameByPeopleID(peopleId);

            treeNodeMap.put(peopleId, new DemoTreeNode(new FolderTree(peopleName, peopleId.toString()), new DemoTreeNode[] {}, true));

        }
        for (Integer peopleIDTemp : peopleIDList) {
            Result<Record> recordList = Transaction.current().select(People.PEOPLE.PEOPLE_ID).from(People.PEOPLE)
                    .where(People.PEOPLE.PARENT_ID.eq(peopleIDTemp)).fetch();

            DemoTreeNode treeNode = (DemoTreeNode) treeNodeMap.get(peopleIDTemp);
            if (recordList.size() > 0) {
                for (Record record : recordList) {
                    peopleID = record.getValue(People.PEOPLE.PEOPLE_ID);
                    DemoTreeNode treeChildNode = treeNodeMap.get(peopleID);
                    treeChildNode.setOpen(true);
                    treeNodeMap.put(peopleID, treeChildNode);
                    treeNode.add(treeChildNode);
                    if (peopleIDTemp == argpeopleID) {
                        parentNodeChildList.add(peopleID);
                    }
                }
            }
            treeNodeMap.put(peopleIDTemp, treeNode);// Here I am putting the treenode and below checking the selected data condition I set the selected peopleTree Node to it selected, but it is not working.
            if (selectedPeopleData.getPeopleID() == peopleIDTemp) {
                setSelectedPeopleTreeNode(treeNode);
            }
        }
        List<DemoTreeNode> rootNodeChildList = new ArrayList<DemoTreeNode>();
        rootNodeChildList.add(treeNodeMap.get(argpeopleID));
        DemoTreeNode[] rootNodeArray = new DemoTreeNode[rootNodeChildList.size()];
        rootNodeChildList.toArray(rootNodeArray);
        DemoTreeNoderootNode = new DemoTreeNode(null, rootNodeArray, true);
        peopleTreeModel = new DemoTreeModel(rootNode);

        BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, this, "peopleTreeModel");
        BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, this, "selectedPeopleTreeNode");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  `selectedItem="@bind(vm.selectedPeopleTreeNode)"`

Use bind for instead of load

and you can use Invalidate for your parent component because some time issue arise for notifying  .